# How to convert SASS to CSS?

Tags: css, sass

As the title suggest, I'm looking for an online tool to convert few lines of SASS into pure CSS.. I already Googled it, but every links that I can found were talking about CSS to SASS converters..

Also, here is the few lines that I want to convert into CSS :

```
=text-shadow($color)
  $str: null
  @for $i from 1 through 32
    $str: #{$i}px #{$i}px 0px #{$color}, $str
  text-shadow: $str
```

Comment: Can't you simply compile the SASS? Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: You can't convert *THAT* to CSS. You can work with the result of running that, though. Will it do for you?

Comment: Why not just run the SASS through the compiler?

Comment: To whomever made the first vote to close: I think the question is clear enough. Please don't vote to close like that.

Comment: @Renan: Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Because the point of my "experiment" is to see that code in pure css.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I think your comment is actually the best answer for this.

Comment: SASS produces "pure CSS" when you compile it. So just compile it. Is this the silliest question ever or am I missing something?

Comment: @wesleyMurch Yeah, I could, but that's not what I want to do :/ 
This code works perfectly, I just want to do an other version of the "experiment" with css..

Comment: If you want a quick preview, in the browser, just use [codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/)

Comment: I use it on cssdeck @NickTomlin

Comment: @wesleyMurch : Thanks! I didn't think it could work, I reach to get the "pure css" produced by the compiler, thanks.

Comment: If you want to be able to "loop" like the SASS code in CSS, you cannot. If you simply want the output that the SASS produces to be pure CSS, then compile it (like others have said), copy that compiled code, and go back in and paste it over the SASS code you want "replaced" with the pure CSS.

Comment: @WesleyMurch : In a certain way, yes, but I just would know how to get css output from sass, I didn't know that I can use a web inspector tool to view the css output through an iframe.  But your first comment helps me to understand how compiler works. That's all.. 

Thanks again, should I delete this question ?

Comment: http://sassmeister.com/ will compile SASS for you.

Comment: You're *supposed* to have at least a basic understanding of the subject you're asking about.  Have you looked at the Sass home page or its basic tutorial?  http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html

Comment: You should accept the answer you like most if it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer to your question is:

```
  /* empty */
```

The CSS equivalent of your SASS code is an empty string.

**Explanation**

With `=` you define a mixin. A mixin by itself does not define any CSS rules. But it can be used in rules as a shortcut. Like functions in any programming language. CSS does not support functions, so there is no way to express this SASS code in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Per Wikipedia:

> Sass is a Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) metalanguage. It is a scripting
>   language that is interpreted into CSS. SassScript is the scripting
>   language itself.

As most of the comments have said, SASS is compiled into CSS, so that's what you'll have to do.

Also, as Nick Tomlin mentioned, [codepen](http://codepen.io/) is excellent for front end code such as this, and fully supports SASS.

You can find the SASS source [here](https://github.com/nex3/sass), which should shed some light on the process.

Comment: I guess the obvious needs to be stated from time to time. I'd bet this post might actually be useful to some poor confused soul in the future.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes it could..